# cq5 get parent node properties

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

I have component hierarchy `parsys -> parentcomp -> childcomp`

`parentcomp` node has some properties.
I am trying to access parent `parentcomp` properties at `childcomp` level.

I am not sure how to do this.

Any idea how to get a parent node properties.
I know following code, gives me the path having parent node as one of selector.
But, not sure how to get to exactly specific node and read those properties.

```
<%= currentNode.getPath() %>
```

Thank you,
Sri

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this.

1. Using the [Resource API](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/resource/Resource.html), where the `resource` object is available through inclusion of the `global.jsp`

   `ValueMap parentProps = resource.getParent().getValueMap(); //in latest versions of AEM
   ValueMap parentProps = resource.getParent().adaptTo(ValueMap.class); //older versions`
2. Using the [Node API](http://www.day.com/specs/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html) using the `currentNode` object.

   `PropertyIterator propertyIterator = currentNode.getParent().getProperties()`

I would personally prefer using Resource API to achieve the same as it makes it a lot simpler to handle the properties.

Comment: I used resource approach to achieve this.                                     ValueMap parentProps = resource.getParent().adaptTo(ValueMap.class);

Answer (score 4):

`currentNode` is an instance of the [`Node` interface from the JCR API](http://www.day.com/specs/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html).

A part of `Node`'s contract is the `getParent` method that you can use to obtain a reference to a node's parent JCR Node.

If the content structure is as you describe it, `currentNode.getParent().getProperties()` will get you the properties of the `parentcomp` node. However, if what you're describing are AEM components, you're probably going to have some `jcr:content` nodes in between. Double-check the actual structure in CRXDE.

If you're only interested in a single, specific property, you can just use `getProperty` instead.